# Unable to finish installation/update of Project Spark

Tags: windows-8.1, project-spark

So I was playing the newly released game by Microsoft - "Project Spark" on my Win 8.1, and after a certain update was released, I can´t download the game anymore! Before the game ran normally. I started the game as usual, but it told me there is a new update. I downloaded it, but it seemed to stop downloading at exact 74%. I waited for a few hours, but still nothing. So I re-installed the whole game, to see if it would help. Download froze on the exact same percent. The same went on and on when I tried to re-istall the game 3 more times.

[image: screenshot of the istallation]

What do I do with this? I would be really happy if you helped. PC specs added, if needed. I also have an ~old~ pc, but it still runs nicely

**Edit #1:** I tried freeing some space from my HDD because it was nearly full, but it still doesn´t seem to help.